# Deprecated: Implicit conversion from float to int loses precision

Tags: php

I am playing around with getting hours and minutes out of seconds, and we all see the many many questions that are similar to this, but I am not sure what solution is the best

```
$seconds = 6530;

$secs = $seconds % 60;
$hrs = $seconds / 60;
$mins = $hrs % 60; // Causing the issue
$hrs = $hrs / 60;

var_dump($hrs, $mins, $secs);
```

This is the code, which gives me:

```
Deprecated: Implicit conversion from float 108.83333333333333 to int loses precision 
float(1.8138888888888889)
int(48)
int(50)
```

I understand the error, thats not the issue, the issue is how to solve it. I have tried

```
$mins = (int) ($hrs % 60);

and 

$mins = intval($hrs % 60);

as well as

$mins = (int) round($hrs % 60);
```

But I get the same issue.

Here is the sandbox for reference: https://onlinephp.io/c/b5b45

What is the proper way to solve this? I do want this as an `int`, but not sure how to properly convert it.

Comment: You need to turn `$hrs` into an integer, not `$hrs % 60`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to int your float to int, you can use some function such a `floor` `round` etc..

in your case you are looking for floor so you should do:

```
<?php


$seconds = 6530;

$secs = $seconds % 60;
$hrs = $seconds / 60;
$hrs = floor($hrs);
$mins = $hrs % 60;
$hrs = $hrs / 60;

var_dump($hrs, $mins, $secs);
```

That's giving:

```
float(1.8)
int(48)
int(50)
```

Comment: I would have thought the hours would be 1.

Comment: The general approach makes sense but the specific code in this answer is a bit of a mess— misleading variable names and not taking the floor of hours to get the expected integer value.

(Sorry for the meh comment trying to counteract an update i cannot remove https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423450/why-is-stackoverflow-stopping-me-from-removing-an-upvote-from-an-answer )

Answer (score 4):

The answer that has been approved here doesn't give the correct result. We know the result should be:

```
int(1)
int(48)
int(50)
```

Which is indeed 6530 seconds because: 3600 + 2880 + 50 = 6530.

The correct way to compute this is:

```
$seconds = 6530;

$modulusSeconds = $seconds % 60;
$minutes = intdiv($seconds, 60);
$modulusMinutes = $minutes % 60;
$hours = intdiv($minutes, 60);

var_dump($hours, $modulusMinutes, $modulusSeconds);
```

See: https://3v4l.org/8JKQ9

There is however another way to compute this:

```
$seconds = 6530;

echo gmdate("G i s", $seconds);
```

Which is simpler. This results in:

```
1 48 50
```

Comment: The `gmdate()` approach using time formatters from https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php is very elegant!  Important caveat is that it will not work for times of 24 hours or more.

Answer (score -1):

Use floor(var) function to prevent error