# GD2 won't resize images - deprecated error on Magento 2.4.4-p6 and PHP 8.1

Tags: magento2, gd, php-8.1

Upgraded to latest version of Magento 2.4.4-p6 and now GD2 will not resize my images

> [2023-11-09T00:29:45.553851+00:00] main.CRITICAL: Exception: Deprecated Functionality: Implicit conversion from float -457.5 to int loses precision in /vendor/magento/framework/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 963 in /vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61

Comment: What feature are you using to resize an image? Is this core functionality or a plugin? How do you trigger it?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73653446/deprecated-implicit-conversion-from-float-to-int-loses-precision) indicates the error comes from PHP rather than GD2, and the code will need an adjustment to work.

Comment: The error seems to have been introduced in PHP 8.1, so if you want a quick fix, see if your platform offers an easy downgrade to PHP 8.0.

Comment: No feature. Built in to Magento 2 to resize. Will try downgrade to PHP 8.0

Comment: Downgrade worked but had to add "platform-check": false to composer.json and run composer dump autoload after

Comment: Excellent work on downgrading PHP. The latest stable of Magento is 2.4.6-p3, so I wonder if this would contain the PHP 8.1 GD2 fix.

Comment: Ah, I just found [a plugin fix](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/358281). But it might be worth upgrading to the latest stable first.

Comment: Downgrading did cause an issue with my magent, but I'll try the plugin fix. Unfortunately upgrading to 2.4.6-p3 will be a long process.

Comment: Out of interest, is upgrading a Magento installation complicated? I would have thought it would just replace new files and do a database migration with a little downtime penalty.

Comment: Its not the magento that is the issue, its any 3rd party extensions or customizations added. Costs to update the extension or extension conflicts can cause an upgrade to potentially be a headache. Also the testing involved.